# Elementor page layout not reflected on live site

Tags: wordpress, layout, styling, elementor

When previewing my page using Elementor, everything is nicely aligned.

When I look at the live site

- the section is not boxed, but full width
- The input fields are a couple of pixels wide rather than the 30%/70% split of the section width I had configured
- The button does not stretch for the width of the section, but is a certain size (no idea where that specific size comes from).

TLDR, the layout of my Elementor page is not reflected on the live site

---

I tried the suggestions I find all over the web

- clear browser cache
- clear cache on Elementor preview page
- Elementor > Tools > Regenerate CSS
- Elementor > Settings > Advanced: change CSS Print method

but to no avail.

---

When looking at the HTML code, I don't see any coding that specifies the 30/70 split or the size of the button or the fact the page should contain a centered section for example

```
[](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mCd19.png)
[](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8FA82.png)
[](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mnFHp.png)
[](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XbesR.png)
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. Wordpress had temp.domains address in site_url rather than my actual domain, so when I went to my domain URL it couldn't find the images or CSS files since they were still referring to the temp.domains URL. Updated the Site Address and Wordpress Address and that solved the issue. Can be closed